# Is thanking Allah and someone shirk

Tags: shirk

Is saying I give thanks to Allah and so and so shirk? Or saying
if it wasn’t for Allah and so-so? For example: Someone gives you a car and you can finally drive to work and you say “If it weren’t for Allah and so and so I wouldn’t be able to drive to work.” Or if you tell someone about the person giving you the car and they say “We give thanks to Allah and so and so.” Would saying those things be shirk?

Answer (score 0):

Shirk is associating people or things with Allah, Allah is one and not related to anything or anyone. Also in what situation are you thanking other people alongside thanking Allah? Are you making a dua just to thank others? If you want to thank others you should tell them. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not shirk if you say thanks both to Allah from Whom all comes and the particular person who helped you. Allah always helps through someone or something. That means that we can bless Allah and say thanks to the person who did His Will. His servant.

Answer (score -2):

Thanking others for what Allah has given you is shirk.

Comment: This needs some more elaboration. See [answer].